# Как после закрытия application, автоматически закрыть и все его оповещения?

Tags: android, уведомления, activity-life-cycle

Есть плеер у которого есть Notification который регулирует воспроизведение музыки. И мне надо что-бы после полного закрытия приложения (а не ухода в фон) я мог закрыть этот Notification. onDestroy() не вызываеться когда приложение уходит в бек.
Application.onTerminate() тоже не вариант.

Comment: В Андроиде нет такого понятия, как "полное закрытие приложения". Что Вы понимаете под закрытием application? Наверное нужно убирать уведомления там же, где Вы останавливаете плеер.

Answer (score 0):

В такой ситуации имеет смысл использовать foreground service - показывать уведомление из сервиса через метод `startForeground`. В этом случае, даже если пользователь завершит приложение из recents, процесс не завершится, а сервис продолжит работать.